# How to get the image path from data URL

Tags: php, image

So my problem that when I upload an image to the server and get the link (copy the link location of image)  and paste it into the browser the image display normally but I want want to get the path of the image

It looks like this on the URL

```
data:image;base64,PD9waHAKZmlsZV9wdXRfY29udGVudHMoIi4vdXAucGhwIiwgZm9wZW4oImh0dHA6Ly9wYXN..........
```

long base64 string

I want to know the path of the image
because it is hidden with this base64 code. I tried to decode it but nothing new.

Comment: Thats a representation of the image encoded in base64. There's no path available because there's no file in the filesystem. If you take that string and put it in `<img src="data:image...">` you should see the image.

Comment: In short what @castis is saying, your `long base64 string` is the image.

Comment: i know the is string of base64  but i  uploded a php script instead the image and still coud not find the path of my php script it display like the image

data:image,.....